# MPI one-sided communication with user callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, mpi

To overlap MPI communications and computations, I am working on issuing asynchronous I/O (MPI calls) with user-defined computation function on the data from I/O.

MS-Window's 'Overlap' is not the friend of MPI (It supports for overlapped I/O only for File I/O and Socket communication, but not for MPI operations...)

I cannot find an appropriate MPI API for it, is there anyone with a glimpse on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no completion callbacks in MPI. Non-blocking operations always return a request handle that must be either be synchronously waited on using `MPI_Wait` and family or periodically tested using the non-blocking `MPI_Test` and family.

With the help of either `MPI_Waitsome` or `MPI_Testsome`, it is possible to implement a dispatch mechanism that monitors multiple requests and calls specific functions upon their completion. None of the MPI calls has any timeout characteristics though - it is either "wait forever" (`MPI_Wait...`) or "check without waiting" (`MPI_Test...`).